# google ai platform vs ml engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-ai

I did lots of search, but I cannot understand what the difference between `google ai platform` and `ml engine`.

It seems that both of them can be used for training and deploying models.

Other words like google-cloud-automl, google ai hub are also very confusing.

What are the differences between them? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: there isn't. In 2019 "ML Engine" was renamed to "AI Platform" and in time some services changed and expanded. To see what has changed, check the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/release-notes), starting from around April. "Around", as they haven't left much trace that ML Engine ever existed.

Here's one of [pull requests](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/pull/2105) to "Rename Cloud ML Engine to AI Platform" for Python samples.

Answer (score 3):

**[Cloud ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs)** = **AI Platform Training + AI Platform Prediction** (It was just a name change). Used for training and deploying ML models.

- AI Platform Training: Bring your own code and submit Training jobs using supported ML frameworks such as TensorFlow, scikit-learn, XGBoost, Keras, etc.
- AI Platform Prediction: Host your Model and use AI Platform Prediction to infer target values for new data.

**[Google Cloud Auto ML](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs)** = You don't need to code, bring your dataset and GCP automatically picks the best model for you.

[image]

Different products:

- Vision
- Video Intelligence
- Natural Language
- Translation
- Tables.

**[Google AI Hub](https://cloud.google.com/ai-hub)** = It is a Catalog: Discover Notebooks, Models and Pipelines.

Edit: Now AI Platform is called Vertex AI

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the previous ML Engine service is now under [Cloud AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform) portfolio of products and provides end-to-end platform to build, run, and manage ML projects.

Please follow the instructions on how to use the service [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples).