# Did GCP ML Engine get rebranded?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It seems that ML Engine is no longer a product of GCP. Did it get re-branded as part of AI platform? I tried searching for the ML Engine documentation and there's no result on that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackoverflow post reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585131/google-ai-platform-vs-ml-engine#:%7E:text=Cloud%20ML%20Engine%20%3D%20AI%20Platform,%2C%20XGBoost%2C%20Keras%2C%20etc.)
The previous ML Engine service is now under [Cloud AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform). It provides end-to-end platform to build, run, and manage ML projects, as well as deploying your models at scale and get predictions from them.